# How to give Android 3.2 same look as Android 2.2 application?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-3.2-honeycomb

I have developed an Android application targeting Android 2.2 now I want to make it compatible with Android 3.2
I am facing the following interface differences between these two apps

1. EditText background
2. Tab host size; I gave fill_parent which work perfectly in Android 2.2 on all devices but   in Android 3.2 it reduces its size to almost half of screen.
3. Background color of Buttons are different
4. Font size in Android 3.2 is smaller than Android 2.2 application.

etc ... etc

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 3.2 use `<resource>-sw600dp` e.g `drawable-sw600dp` and `values-sw600dp` with combination of

`res/layout/main_activity.xml`           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

`res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml`   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

`res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml`   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

Here is reference:
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Answer (score 0):

you can use different resource-folder for different versions:

for example

```
values <-- default
values-v11 for Honeycomb and bigger
```

or

```
layout
layout-v11
```

and so on...

in these folders you can declare different styles, dimensions, values, layouts and so on

Comment: for that How do we know if the underline OS is Honeycomb or Gingerbread ... Or this - v11 will automatically work for those